# What are the side-effects for users after disabling an available country in AppStore Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We have a released app on the iOS AppStore that is marked as available in 4 specific countries.

We would like to remove the app from 1 of those territories, so that it isnt downloadable for *new* users. Does anyone know what the experience will be for existing users of our app in that removed country?

The main question we have is, if we release updates to the app, will the existing users in this disabled country still be able to receive those updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my main question. We had already removed a different territory from our app, and today received a support message from a user.

When they tried to update the app they got the following message: " no longer available. The developer has removed the app."

So if you remove an existing app from a territory, existing users in that territory will not be able to receive updates.